# Showing leaderboard crashes app because showViewController isn't supported

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, ios8, game-center-leaderboard

What is the right way to present Game Center leaderboards in iOS 7? The code below crashes on `showViewController` because it only supports iOS 8. Other Stack Overflow posts suggest using `presentViewController` for iOS 7, but that only shows a blank leaderboard.

```
func showLeaderboards() {
    // User logged into GameCenter?
    if (!GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated) {
        println("Local player not authenticated")
        // Show message
        return
    }

    // If here, user authenticated. Present leaderboards.
    var gcViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self
    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
    gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = HighScoresLeaderboardKey
    self.showViewController(gcViewController, sender: self)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gcViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app targets iOS 7.x, you should use the following code:

```
self.presentViewController(gcViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

instead of:

```
self.showViewController(gcViewController, sender: self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but presentViewController shows an empty leaderboard (i.e., no leaderboards tab, no challenges tab). If we use showViewController on an iOS 8 device, it shows a populated leaderboard. Is there something else we need to do with presentViewController so it shows something?

Comment: i am a beginner of GameKit,i am sorry that i can't help you to solve you "shows an empty leaderboard"

Comment: Thanks, but do you know why the result differs when we use presentViewController instead of showViewController for an iOS 8 device?

Comment: Actually seems to work now, thanks! No clue why it didn't work at first.